# RegExp - Detect string with a changing number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string like this one:

```
A customer with the id '2589' already exists.
```

The number can change, the other words are the same everytime. How can I detect if it is this message, regardless of the number?

So I am thinking of something like this:

```
$str = 'A customer with the id '2589' already exists.';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $result);

if ($result[0] == 'A' && $result[1] == 'customer' && $result[2] == 'with')...
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you also want to extract number or just want to validate?

Comment: You could just run 2 `str_replace`, by the way, to remove all known parts.

Comment: You want to make sure that the text surrounding the number is always the same? Is the number always the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A customer with the id '(\d+)' already exists\.
```

Use `\d` detect the number and `+` for 1 or more.

Here is an explanation: https://regex101.com/r/3lEsI4/2

If you need to set the min length of this number only use `{4,}` (min 4 digit)

If you want to set the max of length use `{,6}` (max 6 digit)

If you need to set both of them use `{4,6}` (min 4 and max 6 digit)

For example:

```
A customer with the id '(\d{4,6})' already exists\.
```

So

```
$pattern = "/A customer with the id '(\d+)' already exists\./";
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$str = 'A customer with the id '2589' already exists.';
$isAMatch = preg_match("/A customer with the id \'(\d)+\' already exists\./", $str);
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the last `.`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just search for "A customer with the number" and for "already exists"?  If both are found then you're probably looking at one of these messages